# W3CSS: fluid layout to center the page?

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

I use the W3CSS to build a responsive site.
To center the page I thought, I'd use the 12-column system they provide. So I did something like this:

```
<div class="w3-container">
    <div class="w3-row">
        <div class="w3-col m2 l3 w3-container w3-blue"></div>
        <div class="w3-col m8 l6 w3-container w3-white">
            <p>
                Hello world!
                <br>
                <br>
                Let's do this.
                <br>
                <br>
                A lot of fun...
            </p>
        </div> <!-- Content Column -->
    <div class="w3-col m2 l3 w3-container w3-red"></div>
    </div> <!-- Content Container Row -->
</div> <!-- Page Container -->
```

I had to assign the class `w3-container` to the `w3-col`. Otherwise the layout wouldn't work. The downside of adding `w3-container` is, that the w3-color-classes won't apply anymore.
This is exactly **my problem**: I want the two divs surrounding the content-div to be have a certain color. But the background-color won't apply. Neither by adding the w3-class nor by adding it manually via CSS.

Here's the whole JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/timothys_monster/kp445w0u/10/

Comment: Try using bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com) its a lot more powerful

Comment: @DovBenyominSohacheski Thanks for the recommendation, but it's a bit _too_ powerful for my taste. I find it way easier to work with W3CSS for the moment. Also, it's easier to adjust the core CSS file in comparison to Bootstrap, I think.

Comment: Can you reframe your question to understand exactly what it is you're looking to accomplish?

Comment: @DovBenyominSohacheski done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.w3-content` class for a selected parent element and then you should set max-width for it like 1200px or so. Inside of it you can use your 12-column grid as wanted. Check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_responsive_content&stacked=h)

Comment: Thanks, that's indeed what I was looking for. Way easier to implement and responsive, too. Great!